# btrfs filesystem end offset (image size)

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, disk-image

I have a btrfs filesystem of about 7G in a 10G image file `img.btrfs` (I shrank it using `btrfs fi resize -3G /mnt`). How can I find the total size (end byte offset) of the filesystem, so that I can shrink the image size? I.e. find out `$SIZE` for

```
truncate -s $SIZE img.btrfs
```

A mechanism that applies to any other filesystem inside an image file would be a plus.

**NOTE**: one thing that *does* work is:

```
INITIAL=$(stat -c %s img.btrfs)
mount img.btrfs /mnt
btrfs fi resize -$NBYTES /mnt
umount /mnt
truncate -s $((INITIAL - NBYTES + 1024*1024)) img.btrfs
mount /img.btrfs /mnt
btrfs fi resize max /mnt
```

i.e. shrink the btrfs, shrink the image by a little bit less (leaving a 1M overhead), then grow the btrfs to the maximum afforded by the shrunk image.

Comment: Is 7GB the total size of the files, or the size of the filesystem (e.g. because this is an image of a disk containing multiple partitions)?

Comment: The filesystem initially occupied the entire image file (by virtue of `mkfs.btrfs /dev/loop` using up all available space). Then I called `btrfs fi resize -3G /vol/btrfs`.

Comment: ... so I don't know for sure the exact (byte) size of the filesystem inside the image. But I need to find it out, so that I can truncate the image file appropriately. A mechanism that applies to any other filesystem inside an image file would be a plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annoyingly, `btrfs filesystem show` returns an approximate value if the size isn't a multiple of 1MB. It also requires a loop device, `btrfs filesystem show img.btrfs` doesn't work (as of Debian jessie). I can't find another `btrfs` subcommand that would help.

But `file img.btrfs` helpfully returns the desired size.

```
$ truncate -s 16684k /tmp/img.btrfs
$ /sbin/mkfs.btrfs /tmp/img.btrfs
SMALL VOLUME: forcing mixed metadata/data groups
Btrfs v3.17
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Turning ON incompat feature 'mixed-bg': mixed data and metadata block groups
Turning ON incompat feature 'extref': increased hardlink limit per file to 65536
Created a data/metadata chunk of size 1703936
failed to open /dev/btrfs-control skipping device registration: Permission denied
fs created label (null) on /tmp/img.btrfs
        nodesize 4096 leafsize 4096 sectorsize 4096 size 16.29MiB
$ truncate -s 32m /tmp/img.btrfs
$ file /tmp/img.btrfs
/tmp/img.btrfs: BTRFS Filesystem sectorsize 4096, nodesize 4096, leafsize 4096, UUID=61297945-d399-4fdc-ba9f-750ef9f9dfdb, 28672/17084416 bytes used, 1 devices
```

It directly reads the 8-byte little-endian value at offset 0x10070. If you don't want to parse the output of `file`, you can extract it. The following POSIX snippet does the job¹:

```
size_hex=$(cat /tmp/img.btrfs | dd ibs=8 skip=8206 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -tx8 -An | tr abcdef ABCDEF | tr -dc 0-9ABCDEF)
[ ${#size_hex} -eq 16 ] &&
{ echo "ibase=16; $size_hex"; } | bc
```

or in Perl:

```
</tmp/btrfs.img perl -e 'seek(STDIN, 0x10070, 0) or sysread(STDIN, $_, 0x10070) == 0x10070 or die "seek"; sysread(STDIN, $_, 8) == 8 or die "read"; print unpack("Q<", $_), "\n"'
```

`file` works for some other filesystem types, but that doesn't help much for scripts because the output isn't standardized. I can't think of a generic utility with a standard interface for all common filesystems, maybe some virtualization or forensics tool.

¹  <sub>Exercise: why is this a useful use of `cat`?</sub>

Comment: great answer. I was thinking `parted` must have code that does this

Comment: @Anul It must have code to do it, but I haven't seen a way to make it spit it out.

Comment: I don't think this works: `truncate -s 16384987654 /tmp/img.btrfs; mkfs.btrfs /tmp/img.btrfs; file /tmp/img.btrfs` reports `114688/16384987136` used. So the number you get from `file` is not the number you can use in `truncate`. In this case you need to reserve an additional 518 bytes, but that could vary depending on factors.

Comment: I've added my current solution -- though it's annoying and error prone.

Comment: @Anul Your numbers seem fine. On a 16384987654-byte device, btrfs only uses 16384987136 bytes (16384987654 rounded down to a multiple of the block size which is 4kB). The last 518 bytes are unused so you don't need to copy them.

Comment: It's not copying that I'm worried about. I need to know how much i can TRUNCATE the image file so that I don't get access-past-end-of-device errors. How do you know the "final" 518 bytes are unused?

Comment: @Anul I know that because 1. The filesystem size was read from the filesystem, it's what the filesystem driver uses, the filesystem won't read beyond that. 2. I know that a btrfs filesystem consists of an integer number of blocks and has no hole; the mathematical consequence is that the last 518 bytes are not part of any block and are thus not used. This value is exactly what you requested — the btrfs filesystem size (which is equal to its end offset), independently of the size of the volume that it's in.

Comment: I see. So it's a 4096-byte alignment thing -- whatever exceeds a block will not be used anyway.

Comment: Regarding`cat`, is it to do with buffering? What is the advantage?

Comment: @TomHale [See the comment in the answer's source code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/916974dd-7e1d-4f04-84ce-839ec47e8566/view-source)

Answer (score 1):

Both `btrfs filesystem show` and `btrfs filesystem usage` give you the size
of the device, in [Mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibytes),
Gibibytes, or other powers of 2. You can just pass this on to `truncate` with
the suffix M or G etc as these are also in powers of 2 (do not use suffix MB GB!). For example, on a 1G image reduced by 10M:

```
sudo btrfs fi show /mnt
 devid    1 size 1014.00MiB used 12.00MiB path /dev/loop0
sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt
 Device size:                1014.00MiB

SIZE=1014M # not MB!
truncate -s $SIZE img.btrfs
```

There should not be any blocks used beyond this size.

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer, but it does rounding to the nearest multiple of 10485.76 bytes. I don't think you can reliably find the filesystem size from that, because the filesystem size can be (AFAIK) any multiple of 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I'd forgotten that when I got round to reading the question again. I suppose the easy solution is just to round up a few Mbytes further.